# Different quote layout for different record types

Tags: record-type, record

How can i configure that if an opportunity is in record type a when i create a pdf of quote, the layout will be layout a, if an opportunity is record type b, the quote layout will be layout b?
Thanks in advance and PLEASE RESPECT POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to -->

Setup --> Build --> Customize --> Quotes --> Page Layouts --> click the Page Layout Assignment Button --> click the Edit Assignment Button and assign the Page Layout A to Record Type A - and so on.

[image]